# Inverting Rows and Columns in a R Janitor tabyl crosstab

Tags: r, janitor

I have a crosstab using the tabyl function of the janitor package in R.

I want the column on the right to move to the left.
I want the row at the bottom to come to the top.

This is in keeping with conventions in Epidemiology where tables are always represented with people with disease and risk factor being on the top left. Currently that is coming on the bottom right.

This is the code i am using

```
tabyl(diabetes, bmi_dichot , outcome )
```

where diabetes = name of dataset , bmi_dichot is a factor containing values obese or not obese and outcome is a factor containing values diabetic or not diabetec

I want Obesity yes , Diabetes yes persons in the top left column but it is in the bottom right.

Thanks so much.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks. First question on stackoverflow. New to this. I will do this. Thanks